# How to pass Object as parameter

Tags: c++, oop, object, methods, parameters

I'm new to C++ so I will probably have a lot of mistakes. I'm coming from C# and am not quite familiar with methods in C++.

So I have an Elevator class, a Forklift class and a Crate class. I need to pass an Elevator to the constructor of Forklift. From what I have researched this is the way to do it but I still get an error.

In the class Crate I pass an object and it works.

```
Forklift::Forklift(list<Crate> crates, Elevator & elevator)
{
    for each (Crate crate in crates)
    {
        this->cratestack.push(crate);
    }
    this->elevator = elevator;
}
```

It says that Elevator has no default constructor. I know that if I haven't defined one the compiler won't generate one like in C# but do I need it when I won't be using with the default one? I need elevator with these parameters.

Here is the head file for Forklift:

```
class Forklift
{
private:
    Elevator elevator;
    stack<Crate> cratestack;
    stack<Crate> helperstack;
public:
    Forklift(list<Crate> crates,Elevator& elevator);
    ~Forklift();

    int start();
};
```

Here are the elevator head :

```
class Elevator
{
private:
    int minweight;
    int maxweight;
    int currentweight;
    int tours;
public:
    Elevator(int max, int min);
    ~Elevator();

    bool Load(Crate crate);
    int GetTour();
};
```

and source file:

```
Elevator::Elevator( int max, int min)
{
    this->maxweight = max;
    this->minweight = min;
}
Elevator::~Elevator()
{
}

bool Elevator::Load(Crate crate)
{
    if (currentweight + crate.GetWeight() > maxweight)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

int Elevator::GetTour() 
{
    return this->tours;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is also in the scop **Private**. Put that in public

Try it